# Avoiding nested for loops in iterating through complex objects

Tags: java, performance

I have a match table in my app which holds the details of the matches scheduled

[image]

I have a `user` table & a `user_match` table which is a bridge table.

`user_match` table below specifies info on which user follows which match & supports which team.
[image]

Now in my controller method I am returning today's scheduled matches & also check at the same time if the loggedIn user follows the today's scheduled matches.

The problem is I have to run two nested for loops in the process Complexity O(n^2). First I iterate through the current day matches & then for every current day match I iterate through all the matches the user follows & check if the current match is present. I was hoping if I could get rid of the nested for loop, could there be a better way to deal with this.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getTodaysMatches", method=RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody List<Match> getMatchesForCurrentDate(){
    logger.debug("inside /getTodaysMatches CricketController method");

    DateTime currentServerTimeStamp = CricketUtil.getServerDateTime();
    List<Match> currentDayMatchList = this.cricketService.fetchMatchesForInputDate(currentServerTimeStamp);
    CustomUserDetail myUserDetails = currentUserAccessor.getCurrentLoggedInUser();
    User loggedInUser = myUserDetails.getUser();
    List<UserMatchInfo> userMatchInfoList = this.cricketService.getUserMatchInfoByUserId(loggedInUser.getUserId());

    /*check if the logged in user already follows matches scheduled for today*/

    for(Match  todaysMatch : currentDayMatchList){
        for(UserMatchInfo tmpUserMatchInfo : userMatchInfoList){
            String teamFollowedByUser = tmpUserMatchInfo.getSupportingTeam();
            Match matchWhichUserFollows = tmpUserMatchInfo.getMatch();
        if((matchWhichUserFollows.getMatchId().intValue()) == (todaysMatch.getMatchId().intValue())){
            todaysMatch.setLoggedInUserFollowsThisMatch(true);
        }

        if((todaysMatch.getTeamOne().equals(teamFollowedByUser))){
            todaysMatch.setLoggedInUserSupportsTeamOne(true);
        }

        if((todaysMatch.getTeamTwo().equals(teamFollowedByUser))){
            todaysMatch.setLoggedInUserSupportsTeamTwo(true);
        }
      }
    }

    return currentDayMatchList;
}
```

Comment: index the data maybe (in some map)

Comment: That is not O(n^2), that is O(n*m) which really is not a big deal. Are you actually facing performance problems - this sounds more like premature optimization?

Comment: Nope I ain't facing any performance problems. The development is in the initial stage so I was hoping to reduce the complexity, avoiding nested for loops but couldn't think of any other way to deal with the situation. It's kinda rule of thumb to avoid nested loops isn't it?

Comment: Then "forget" about performance. Instead focus on creating **readable** code. For example by learning about the "single responsibility" and the "single layer of abstraction" principles. Which would both help improving the quality of your code.

Comment: Option 1: query the database in a more efficient way by simply joining the two tables there already. That way you can make use of the indexing and performance optimizations the database has in place. Option 2: do not change anything since the code is presumably not a problem.

Comment: You can't be wanting to return `currentDayMatchList`, right? You're going to create a new list, add those that pass validation to it and return it, right?

Comment: I want to return currentDayMatchList which is a list of Match. I just have to put some setters on every element of the list based on the condition in the code & then return it.

Comment: If you're really against nested fors and not willing to change the DB query, the alternative is to do the intersection in Java. More code, more hashmaps, no nested for loops, but ultimately the same result.

Comment: @Compass could you give in idea of the code in the answer. I tried that approach but couldn't completely write it. The outer object is the Match & the inner is the UserMatchInfo based on the inner object value/property the outer's setter method is put.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lists you've provided are somewhat unwieldy because you search for the Map by ID, which is a child of the Object, so it looks like an O(n^2) nested for loop, when it can be optimized to O(n).

Instead, convert the List into a HashMap by ID for O(n).

```
HashMap<Integer, Match> matchMap = new HashMap<>();

for(Match m : currentDayMatchList) {
    int id = m.getMatchId().intValue()
    matchMap.put(id, m);
}
```

This gives us a HashMap that is mapped by indices, and a keyset with the IDs. Now we don't have to iterate through the Match over and over. Instead, we can do an O(1) get.

```
for(UserMatchInfo tmpUserMatchInfo : userMatchInfoList){
    String teamFollowedByUser = tmpUserMatchInfo.getSupportingTeam();
    Match matchWhichUserFollows = tmpUserMatchInfo.getMatch();
    if(matchMap.get(matchWhichUserFollows.getMatchId().intValue()) {
        //... etc.

    }
}
```

As you can see, the for loop has been split apart, so rather than doing the UserMatch info for every Match, you're doing the UserMatch info once and then doing an O(1) from the Map, so performance is O(2n) = O(n).